# How to detect on which screen the application launches?

Tags: c#

I work on a WPF Application. I have two monitors connected to the same machine.
I launch the application. How can I detect on which of the two screens the application is launched via code (C#)? Thanks!

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [`Screen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class? To get the current screen use the static method `FromControl` and pass your control as an argument. Then you can check the device name or `Primary` property to detect if you are on the primary monitor.

Comment: You can call that after you application has finished launching.

Comment: I read about it and tried to make it work, but I don't have a reference to any control from the location in code where I want to perform the mentioned check (a static class). I also read about GetWindowThreadProcessId, but not sure of how to use it.